# Is it possible to get Twitter REST search gzip'ed?

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter, gzip

I'm using $.ajax to get a REST search from Twitter with jQuery on client-side. Is it possible to get this gzipped from Twitter? I've searched around, but can't seem to find a definitive answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Twitter provides gzip compression for the Streaming API [as of Febuary 2012](https://dev.twitter.com/blog/gzip-compression-for-stream-twitter-com-this-week), but doesn't appear to provide it for any of their other API endpoints.